# No surface appear when plotting a function with given constraints

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, nan

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy import nan, linspace, meshgrid
x1=linspace(0,2,50)
x2=linspace(0,2,50)
x1, x2 = meshgrid(x1, x2)
f=((x1+1.5)**2+5*(x2-1.7)**2)*((x1-1.4)**2+0.6*(x2-0.5)**2)
f[-x1<=0] = nan
f[-x2<=0] = nan
f[3*x1-x1*x2+4*x2-7<=0] = nan
f[2*x1+x2-3<=0] = nan
f[3*x1-4*x2**2-4*x2<=0] = nan
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.plot_surface(x1, x2, f, cmap=cm.jet,linewidth=0, antialiased=False,label="Kurva $f(x_1,x_2)$",alpha=1)
ax.set_xlabel('$x_1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$x_2$')
ax.set_zlabel('$f(x_1,x_2)$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want to plot `f=((x1+1.5)**2+5*(x2-1.7)**2)*((x1-1.4)**2+0.6*(x2-0.5)**2)`
with given 5 constraints:

- `-x1<=0`
- `-x2<=0`
- `3*x1-x1*x2+4*x2-7<=0`
- `2*x1+x2-3<=0`
- `3*x1-4*x2**2-4*x2<=0`

When I run the code above, nothing appear in the figure. What is my mistake? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `x1` and `x2` as:

```
x1=linspace(0,2,50)
x2=linspace(0,2,50)
```

so each value of them is between `0` and `2`. Then you edit them with:

```
x1, x2 = meshgrid(x1, x2)
```

At this point, `x1` and `x2` are no longer arrays, but matrices. Anyway, as before, each element within them is still between `0` and `2`.
If you apply this filter:

```
f[-x1<=0] = nan
```

then each element of `f` becomes `nan`, since all elements of `x1` are positive, so the expression `-x1<=0` evaluates to `False` for every element of `x1`. The same logic applies for the filter:

```
f[-x2<=0] = nan
```

So, indeed, every element of `f` is `nan` and the plot is empty.
If you try to remove both of the above filters, then you get:

```
f[3*x1-x1*x2+4*x2-7<=0] = nan
f[2*x1+x2-3<=0] = nan
f[3*x1-4*x2**2-4*x2<=0] = nan
```

[image]